# Prevent creation of a webpage by URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, mediawiki, restriction

I have a MediaWiki 1.32.0 website. MediaWiki website directories contains the file `LocalSettings.php` in which one could write global custom PHP.

As a non PHP programmer I ask if there is some PHP command I could use to restrict access to a certain existing webpage, by that webpage's URL, so that any web request to create it('s HTML) would be denied, either resulting in some 404-like HTTP status code, or a redirection to homepage, as long as that command appears in `LocalSettings.php`?
<sub>I would prefer a PHP way instead an Apache PCRE directive in `.htacess`. Also, I should note that the URL is already blocked by `robots.txt`.</sub>

Comment: _Small Point_ `robots.txt` does not actually block anything, its existance tells NiceBots to ignore things. It could also be said it tells NastyBots where to go look for the good stuff. But basically even looking at it is optional

Comment: You might want to add a MediaWiki tag on this question to get better help, as it seems specific to MediaWiki.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: if a specific page of your wiki should not get accessed in any way, why not simply remove it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I need a fast way to access and not access it because I work on it slowly, it is a large article requiring much revision.

Comment: You can use PHP's _ _DIR_ _ or _ _FILE_ _ to detect which URL/page is being accessed and put it in an if statement to decide what to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to [prevent access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access) to wiki content?

Comment: @Tgr yes and no because I look for a non MediaWiki solution - a PHP bypass if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the requested URL in PHP like this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And deny access to a page like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($url == "/wiki/blocked_page") die('404 error here');
```

Or redirect to your home page like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($url == "/wiki/blocked_page") header('Location: /');
```

Note: request_url is everything after your domain name.
If your URL is https://example.com/wiki/blocked_page request_url would return "/wiki/blocked_page".